# Can't ping default gateway in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

I can't ping my default gateway in ubuntu. 
I'm using network-manager so my /etc/network/interfaces is like this

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Here is my other settings

## ifconfig -a

eth0

```
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:bc:12:9e:f9:7b  
      inet addr:192.168.2.200  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:793672 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:322574 errors:0 dropped:2587 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:1053501845 (1.0 GB)  TX bytes:39413163 (39.4 MB)
      Interrupt:43
```

lo

```
      Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:46286 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:46286 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:12308634 (12.3 MB)  TX bytes:12308634 (12.3 MB)
```

vmnet1

```
      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:01  
      inet addr:192.168.191.1  Bcast:192.168.191.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:809 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

vmnet8

```
      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:08  
      inet addr:192.168.38.1  Bcast:192.168.38.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:809 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

## route -n

```
 Kernel IP routing table
 Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use    Iface
 0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
 192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
 192.168.38.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet8
 192.168.191.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vmnet1
```

## arp

```
 Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask                 Iface
 192.168.2.1              ether   08:5b:0e:3a:d3:ed   C                     eth0
```

I have to unplug network cable or restart network-manager to fix this for 5 minutes and then it happens again.
I used wireshark to monitor network traffic. Apperantly, gateway is not responding to arp requests. I have another windows machine connected to it and it's working just fine.